schedule notification is not works in Flutter
I want that after I put time on text edit field the it will send notification on particular time
but normal notification for current time is coming but notification for later is not works
I am using local notification
https://pub.dev/packages?q=flutter+local+notification[text]
NotificationService
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
// Define the background notification response handler
void backgroundNotificationResponseHandler(NotificationResponse notification) async {
  print('Received background notification response: $notification');
  // Handle the background notification response here
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    // Initialize the timezone package
    tz.initializeTimeZones();

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationAndroidSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      defaultPresentSound: true,
      defaultPresentAlert: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {
        print('Received local notification: $id, $title, $body, $payload');
      },
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationAndroidSettings,
      iOS: initializationSettingIOS,
    );

    await notificationPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: backgroundNotificationResponseHandler,
    );

    // Request exact alarm permission for Android 12+
    await requestExactAlarmPermission();
  }

  Future<void> requestExactAlarmPermission() async {
    if (await Permission.scheduleExactAlarm.isDenied) {
      await Permission.scheduleExactAlarm.request();
    }
  }

  Future<void> showNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
  }) async {
    print('Showing notification: $id, $title, $body, $payload');
    await notificationPlugin.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      await notificationDetails(),
      payload: payload,
    );
  }

  Future<NotificationDetails> notificationDetails() async {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channelId',
        'channelName',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
    required DateTime scheduledDate,
  }) async
  {
    // Specify the Indian timezone
    final location = tz.getLocation('Asia/Kolkata');

    // Create a TZDateTime object in the Indian timezone
    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())){
      final tz.TZDateTime scheduledTZDate = tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledDate, location);
      await notificationPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        scheduledTZDate,
        await notificationDetails(),
        payload: payload,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      );
    }



  }

  Future<void> cancelNotification(int id) async {
    await notificationPlugin.cancel(id);
  }
}


and TimeView.dart
import 'package:basics/model/TimeModel.dart';
import 'package:basics/services/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:basics/widget_helper/textbutton.dart';
import 'package:basics/widget_helper/widget_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Timeview extends StatefulWidget {
  const Timeview({super.key});

  @override
  State<Timeview> createState() => _TimeviewState();
}

class _TimeviewState extends State<Timeview> {
  List<TimeModel> timerList = [];
  final NotificationService _notificationService = NotificationService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 60,),
            Text("Reminder"),

            for (int i = 0; i < timerList.length; i++)
              getTimerList(timerList[i], i, () {
                setState(() {

                });
              }),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                 timerList.add(TimeModel());
                  setState(() {

                  });
                },
                child: getTxtColor(
                    msg: "+ Add More Time",
                    txtColor: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 15)),



          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getTimerList(TimeModel item, int index, Function onTap) {
    TextEditingController medicineTimeCont = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController periodCont = TextEditingController();

    if (item.time?.isEmpty == false && item.time != "null") {
      medicineTimeCont.text = "${item.time}";
      periodCont.text = "${item.timeFormat}";

    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 40,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: edtRectField(
                        hint: "Select Time",
                        control: medicineTimeCont,
                        isReadOnly: true,
                        onTap: () {
                          displayTimePicker(
                                  (String time, String format,
                                  DateTime selectedDateTime){
                                    timerList[index] = TimeModel(time: time,timeFormat: format);
                                    onTap();
                                    _scheduleNotification(selectedDateTime, index);
                                    _testNotification();
                                  }
                          );
                        })),
                const SizedBox(width: 6),
                Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: edtRectField(
                        control: periodCont,
                        hint: "Time",
                        isReadOnly: true,
                        onTap: () {
                          displayTimePicker(
                                  (String time, String format,
                                  DateTime selectedDateTime){
                                timerList[index] = TimeModel(time: time,timeFormat: format);
                                onTap();
                                _scheduleNotification(selectedDateTime, index);
                              }
                          );
                        })),
                Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          timerList.removeAt(index);
                          onTap();
                          _cancelNotification(index);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear)))
              ])),
    );
  }

  Future displayTimePicker(
      Function(String time, String formate, DateTime selectedDateTime)
      selectedTimeClick) async {
    TimeOfDay now = TimeOfDay.now();
    TimeOfDay adjustedTime = TimeOfDay(hour: now.hour,minute: now.minute);
    await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime:adjustedTime)
        .then((selectedTime) {
      if (selectedTime != null) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        DateTime selectedDateTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day,
            selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute);
        String formattedTime = DateFormat('hh:mm').format(selectedDateTime);
        final period = selectedTime.period == DayPeriod.am ? 'AM' : 'PM';
        selectedTimeClick(formattedTime, period, selectedDateTime);
      }
    });
  }
  void _scheduleNotification(DateTime dateTime, int index) {
    _notificationService.scheduleNotification(
      id: index,
      body: "Reminder",
      payload: "now",
      title: "New Notification",
      scheduledDate: dateTime,
    );
  }

  void _cancelNotification(int id) {
    _notificationService.cancelNotification(id);
  }
  void _testNotification() async {
    await _notificationService.showNotification(
      id: 0,
      title:timerList[0].time.toString(),
      body: 'This is a test notification',
    );
  }

}


like + Add More Time
I will select time for reminder
and it will for only one day like I set a alarm
and  I am working json no shared preference , no db
